# How to send response to shell script at once

Tags: shell, sh

I have a build in installation script install.sh which when executed asks for following responses

```
$ sh install.sh
Enter Name:
Enter email id:
Enter password :
Confirm password:
```

I want to automate this installation script using shell script and want to send responses to this script at once

How should I do that?

Comment: Consider making your prompts conditional. `if [ -z "$name" ]; then echo "Enter Name: "; read -r name; fi` will only prompt for name if it wasn't passed to your script through the environment.

Comment: ...generally speaking, it's a good practice to separate your programmatic interfaces (which need to stay stable over time for purposes of other software you're integrating with / being called from / etc) from your user interfaces (which are being used to interact with humans who can read and follow instructions, and so which can change at will).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file with one input per line:

```
./script < inputfile
```

[Other details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line)

Comment: This is far from futureproof -- it means that if the order of prompts is ever changed or new prompts are added, the file will then be providing incorrect inputs. Much better to update the script to read from environment variables (`name=foo sh install.sh`) or explicit command-line options (`sh install.sh --name=foo`, &c) instead.